# Heroku Java Tomcat ServletContextListener not calling contextDestroyed on slugc or restart

Tags: tomcat, servlets, heroku, sigterm

Heroku uses SIGTERM to allow processes to gracefully shutdown. However the Tomcat process does not respond to SIGTERM and the never calls contextDestroyed on my ServletContextListener.

How do I get Tomcat to call contextDestroyed using Heroku restarts or when Heroku does a slug compilation for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The shutdown hook wasn't registered to trigger a graceful shutdown of Tomcat so the context wasn't cycling through the shutdown lifecycle events. The latest version of webapp-runner fixes this: https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner/issues/22